# how to use mysql partitioning with row number to return item by type

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

Am trying to select record from database table using mysql `PARTITION` and multiple `INNER JOIN`, to return 3 records each, based on product type.

The problem am facing now is, the user am selecting record from has more than 5 product type in 'GROCERY, FOOD and DRINK', but my query will return 3 drinks, 2 groceries and 1 food, even if i change the partition limit it still doesn't return as expected.

Here is my query

```
SELECT sl.business_name, sl.business_country, sl.seller_private_key,  p.product_name, p.product_id,  p.product_price,  p.product_type, p.product_added_date, p.product_seller_key
FROM (
    SELECT p.product_name, p.product_id,  p.product_price,  p.product_type, p.product_added_date, p.product_seller_key,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.product_type ORDER BY p.product_type) AS limit_group
    FROM seller_stores_products p
    WHERE p.product_availability IN(1,2)
) p

INNER JOIN seller_account sl
ON p.product_seller_key = sl.seller_private_key

INNER JOIN seller_stores st
ON st.store_seller_key = sl.seller_private_key

WHERE limit_group <= 5

    AND sl.seller_private_key = "t9HfbiEDzIXyHjvx57uI"
    GROUP BY p.product_id

ORDER BY sl.seller_private_key ASC, p.product_added_date DESC
LIMIT 25
```

[Also a fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c8d8ea54d633b8412bb799880aea403e)

Expected result is to select maximum of 3 records only if more than three for each product type.

Comment: *"Expected result is to select maximum of 3 records only if more than three for each product type. "* See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as that GROUP BY usage seams to be wrong..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i added a link to fiddle here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c8d8ea54d633b8412bb799880aea403e

Comment: *" i added a link to fiddle here"* Your `GROUP BY` usage is wrong making those results simply not trustworthy ... Besides we are not here to think for you what the results should be.. MySQL 8 does it correct as [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pX3tq19BkLa7bW7LRLHKjb/0) is what should have happend.. Not sure if MariaDB supports that sql_mode as MariaDB is designed as a drop in replacement for MySQL..  ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i tried this also didn't work https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aK9GqQX2JvyZx3xXqssRAB/0

Comment: We have differing definitions of 'Minimal' :-(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need below query -

```
SELECT business_name
      ,business_country
      ,seller_private_key
      ,product_name
      ,product_id
      ,product_price
      ,product_type
      ,product_added_date
      ,product_seller_key
FROM (SELECT sl.business_name
            ,sl.business_country
            ,sl.seller_private_key
            ,p.product_name
            ,p.product_id
            ,p.product_price
            ,p.product_type
            ,p.product_added_date
            ,p.product_seller_key
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.product_type ORDER BY p.product_type) AS limit_group
      FROM seller_stores_products p
      JOIN seller_account sl ON p.product_seller_key = sl.seller_private_key
      WHERE sl.seller_private_key = "t9HfbiEDzIXyHjvx57uI"
      AND p.product_availability IN(1,2)
      ORDER BY sl.seller_private_key ASC, p.product_added_date DESC
      LIMIT 25) X
WHERE limit_group <= 3
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c621b907f9d6e2a49d1d225b6d80018e) is the demo.

Comment: Topicstarter be aware  as `ORDER BY sl.seller_private_key ASC, p.product_added_date DESC` in this case is a non deterministic  `order by` condition meaning where records are ties you can not predict the sort order within the ties besides that order also can change on every execution..  Batching / pagination in SQL always requires atleast a deterministic  sort condition meaning at least  one column in the `ORDER BY`needs to be added where you know for sure the data is unique meaning a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key.

Comment: . ... Same counts for `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.product_type ORDER BY p.product_type)` part..

Comment: If i change the limit_group to 4 or 5 it doesn't work. Can you see it from your end?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i removed the `ORDER BY` entirely but still same also when i change the order type.

Comment: @Peter, I have checked it with 4 and 5. Only 4 and 5 records are coming respectively.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai can you use 4, you will see that only 2 `FOOD` are selected. And if you use 5 `DRINK` will drop by 1 and `GROCERY` will still remain 4 while `FOOD` are 2

Comment: Are you sure you are using my demo because I have tried both and I got the correct result. Here is the link for 4 records https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=65881560642625c20b10e75d68d5f2e0 and here is the link for 5 records https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c5bdd48b46ee5b0a532b767007cd40a7